# Remove Users from MailList based on Bounce Message

Tags: email, delphi, email-bounces

What is the best way to figure out which email users can be removed from their bounce mail message?
Example being a bounce mail error code of 5.1.1, where the mailbox no longer exists.
I'm using the mbox file format from Thunderbird.

My ideas include searching for Status: 5.1.1 then looking ~2 lines down to see the X-Display-Name: example@online.de.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eugene. Your question is not specific enough to be answered. Do you want to write to a specific email client API to scan the mail, write your own client, or are you picking up the mail in your software, in which case, how?  The more specific your question is, the more likely you'll get an answer that helps.

Comment: I have a giant file from Mozilla Thunderbird that contains all the emails. My ideas include searching for Status: 5.1.1 then looking ~2 lines down to see the X-Display-Name: example@online.de. I am willing to look at alternative ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you handle bounces is the way the ezmlm bounce handler does it. It sends a series of bounce messages to the address that bounced to test whether the bounce was temporary or permanent. They describe their technique in a fair bit of detail on [their Bounces and Automated Bounce Handling help page](http://support.kavi.com/khelp/kmlm/user_help/html/bounces.html).

There is Jason Rowe's excellent blog post on [Sending Email and Bounce Handling Rules.](http://jasonrowe.com/2010/03/26/sending-email-and-bounce-handling-rules/)

Also check out [these Bounce Handling Best Practices](http://www.b2bemailmarketing.com/2007/08/bounce-handling.html).

Or you can manually code which messages you want to bounce based on the bounce mail code. You can get [the list of all codes in RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463) which explains what each one means and what type of failure they are.

Deciding what is a hard or soft bounce isn't a science. It's an art. I've researched and thought of programming this myself, but found it was opening a can of worms. Then I was going to use [phpList](http://www.phplist.com/) and figure out [how its bounce handler worked](http://docs.phplist.com/ProcessBouncesInfo). That was no easier.

What I ended up doing was taking the easy way out and using [LuxSci for my bulk emailing](http://luxsci.com/extranet/high-volume-smtp-email.html) and simply [using their Bounce Analysis](http://luxsci.com/blog/bounce-analysis-for-high-volume-outbound-email-service.html) to inform me which emails are "permanent delivery failures" of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is not a standard way to catch all bounced messages.  For a pile of existing messages, you'll have to analyze the pile and try to extract the most common formats. You could probably handle the majority of the bounced detecting with a moderate number of pattern-match schemes.